# Jquery пробелы в json переменной

Tags: javascript, jquery

как исправить, чтобы после вставки атрибут был без пробелов

в контроллере формирую вот так

```
$dialog->json = json_encode(array(
        'avatar' => $dialog->avatar,
        'user_id' => $dialog->user_id,
        'fullname' => $dialog->fullname,
        'dialog_id' => $dialog->dialog_id
      ));

      $dialog->actions = json_encode(array(
        'like' => trim($dialog->like_dialog),
        'favorite' => trim($dialog->favorite_dialog),
        'ignore' => $dialog->ignore_dialog
      ));
```

вот функция для вставки в блок содержимое

```
function getItemDialog($dialog) {
    let $newClass = '';
    if($dialog.new > 0) $newClass = 'active';
    $('.contact-list__items-wrap').append(
      '<div class="contact-list__items user-dialog" data-user="' + $dialog.user_id + '" data-dialog="' + $dialog.dialog_id + '" data-info=\''+$dialog.json+'" data-actions=\''+$dialog.actions+'">\n' +
      '<div class="contact-card">\n' +
      '<a href="/' + $dialog.slug + '" target="_blank" class="contact-card__image" style="background-image: url(/storage' + $dialog.avatar + ')"></a>\n' +
      '<div class="contact-card__data">\n' +
      '<div class="contact-card__data--text">\n' +
      '<p class="username">' + $dialog.fullname + '</p>\n' +
      '<p class="last--massage">' + $dialog.replay + '</p>\n' +
      '<p class="typing">\n' +
      '<span>Печатает</span>&nbsp;\n' +
      '<span class="dots-loader">\n' +
      '<span class="dots-loader__dot"></span>\n' +
      '<span class="dots-loader__dot"></span>\n' +
      '<span class="dots-loader__dot"></span>\n' +
      '</span>\n' +
      '</p>\n' +
      '</div>\n' +
      '</div>\n' +
      '</div>\n' +
      '<ul class="contact-card__actions">\n' +
      '<li class="is_new '+$newClass+'">' + $dialog.new + '</li>\n' +
      '<li class="status"></li>\n' +
      '</ul>\n' +
      '</div>'
    );
  }
```

сейчас вставляет вот так

```
data-actions="{" like":0,"favorite":0,"ignore":0}"
```

а надо вот так

```
data-actions="{"like":0,"favorite":0,"ignore":0}"
```

на скрине видно как выводит
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

кстати используйте лучше современный javascript

```
$('.contact-list__items-wrap').append(
      `<div class="contact-list__items user-dialog" data-user="${dialog.user_id}" data-dialog="${dialog.dialog_id}" data-info="${dialog.json}" data-actions="${dialog.actions}">`);
);
```

вот в этом примере никаких пробелов нет

```
json = {
    like: 0,
    favorite: 0
}

alert(`text ${JSON.stringify(json)}`);
```

честно говоря не понятно откуда они у вас взялись, в примере ничего нет

Comment: так почему-то не работает

Comment: приветите код, в консоли ничего не ругается? когда у себя проверял - все работало

Comment: в консоле выводит так вata-actions="{"like":0,"favorite":0,"ignore":0}"

Comment: на сайте вот так data-actions=" {"like":0,"favorite":0,"ignore":0}" с пробелов в начале

Answer (score 0):

у вас не экранированные кавычки, фактически получается data-actions="{"

```
$('.contact-list__items-wrap').append(
      '<div class="contact-list__items user-dialog" data-user="' + $dialog.user_id + '" data-dialog="' + $dialog.dialog_id + '" data-info="' + $dialog.json + '" data-actions=\''+$dialog.actions+"'>");
);
```

Comment: Изменил вопрос и добавил скрины